# When should I use a Taxonomies Selector in preference to a Subtree?

Tags: importexportservice

In the ImportExport API there exists `Tridion.ContentManager.ImportExport.TaxonomiesSelection` for "selection all taxonomy tree in specific Repository". As Categories are "root items" - direct descendents of the publication, what is the added value of this class? In other words, in what way is it better to export Taxonomies than to simply do a Subtree export of each Category? Does this preserve relationships that you would otherwise miss, and if so, which ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just selects all Taxonomies (Categories & Keywords) rather than specific Categories (plus their Keywords).

If Categories are added to or removed from the Repository, the selection will dynamically change.